# Let a function "return" the super function?

Tags: javascript, function, return, super

Given is the following code:

```
function two() {
    return "success";
}

function one() {
    two();
    return "fail";
}
```

If you test the code by calling function one(), you will always get "fail".

The question is, how can I return "success" in function one() by only calling function two()?

Is that even possible?

Regards

Comment: @Paniyar If he doesn't understand it, he doesn't understand it. Just because it's simple for you doesn't mean it's universally simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make a function return from the function that called it in Javascript (or many other languages, afaik).
You need logic in one() to do it.  E.g.:

```
 function one() {
     return two() || "fail";
 }
```

Comment: Thats plain wrong, "success" || "fail" will fail, neither are boolean

Comment: It's not wrong.  According to the rules of JavaScript, as written by the Ancients of the Web, an or operator (`||`) will return the first argument if it does not evaluate to a 'falsy' value (e.g. false, undefined, null, 0, ""), otherwise it will evaluate and return it's second argument.

Comment: @smirkingman Actually, you're wrong. A string evaluates to a true boolean value in JS. Punch `"success" || "fail"` into any JS console and it will return `"success"`. Know what you're talking about before you bash someone's response.

Comment: Also, +1 to andrewmu for coming up with a creative response!

Comment: And restore my rating to 0 while you're at it!

Comment: Apologies. Edit: Damn, it won't let me undo the -1 and it won't let me +1. Can you edit the answer so I can change it back?

Comment: "fail" || "success" returns "fail" in Chrome's console

Comment: I realise I could simply have written `return two()` and other answers did this.  Without non-local returns (which are a questional feature in any case) you need some logic to in your other function to control what is returned.  I did an idiomatic JavaScript flourish by using the or operator to determine if a non-false value was being returned from two and otherwise return the string "fail".  In some ways I think that is in the spirit of the question, where when we have a non-false evaluating return value from `two`, we return it directly and otherwise return some meaningful value from `one`.

Answer (score 6):

```
function one() {
   return two();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it, using a try-catch Block, if your *function one* anticipates a probable non-local-return as well as *function two* like this using exceptions:

```
function two() {
  throw {isReturn : true, returnValue : "success"}
}


function one () {
  try {
    two()
  } catch(e) {
    if(e.isReturn) return e.returnValue;
  }
  return "fail";
 }
```

, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

```
function one() {    
    return two();
}
```