# Is it possible to implement non-local-returns in JavaScript besides Exceptions?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Can non-local-returns be implemented in JavaScript, so that you could write something like:

```
function some_function() {
  function some_other_function(value) {
   non-local-return true;
  }
  some_other_function();
  return false;
}

true === some_function();
```

where some_function would return true, then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let a function "return" the super function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923920/let-a-function-return-the-super-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, no.

(similar question here: [let-a-function-return-the-super-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923920/let-a-function-return-the-super-function/3923979#3923979))

Answer (score 0):

With some contortions, kind-of yes. You can use exceptions to simulate non-local returns:

```
function boundary(f) {
  try {
    return f();
  } catch (exc) {
    if ("__nlr" in exc) {
      return exc.result;
    } else {
      throw exc
    }
  }
}

function nonLocalReturn(value) {
  throw { __nlr: true, result: value }
}
```

The `boundary` would delimit a scope in which the non-local return can occur, and the `nonLocalReturn` would simply wrap up the "returned" value in a fancy object, and `throw` it.

You *could* (theoretically) use it to implement something like `findFirst` with `forEach`:

```
function findFirstWithForEach(arr, pred) {
  return boundary(() => {
    arr.forEach(elem => {
      if (pred(elem)) {
        nonLocalReturn(elem);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

so that

```
findFirstWithForEach([1, 3, 5, 42, 7, 9], x => x % 2 == 0)
```

would find the `42`.

Your specific example would become

```
function some_function() {
  function some_other_function(value) {
    nonLocalReturn(true);
  }
  return boundary(() => {
    some_other_function();
    return false;
  })
}
```

Obviously, despite being *true*, this has nothing to do with what's good or useful. Please don't use it in any real code.